# Random modules loaded during C# Debug

Tags: c#, .net

It seems every time I debug my application, I have 3 random modules being loaded:

```
'Proj.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'fn0dwwi5'
'Proj.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'qfvavuzb'
'Proj.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'dl4mwhoj'
```

The names change every time I re-start the application.

Any idea as to what these could possibly be?

Regards,
Dan

Comment: Does your code dynamically compile modules using `Reflection.Emit` or CodeDom? *Or* is this a web application?

Answer (score 0):

vshost is an application that VS automatically creates to wrap the console app that you are testing.  It can be ignored, but for more info see [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185331%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: The 'Random modules` the OP is referring to are on the *right* side of their quote: `fn0dwwi5`, `qfvavuzb`, and `dl4mwhoj`. `Proj.vshost.exe` is not the basis of the question.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that vshost is loading those modules which it probably gen'd.   But I don't really know.